# Where is the start menu log stored in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

The order of the Apps in the Start menu as well as the order of the categories they are in have changed sometimes after turning my pc off. Some apps have been outside of the category which I have put them in, others haven't. Some category titles disappeared entirely and some tiles that I have selected to be small have suddenly been displayed large again.

I am suspecting that my antivirus software deletes the logs sometimes, as it has a  disc clean up function built into it. 
If I knew where the log files are that store these infos, I could exclude them from the search and see if that fixes problem.